# Undefined columns selected when subsetting dataframe inside a function

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame called "outcome" with a column called "pneumonia" and some other column like "State" and "Hospital.Name"

when I run in the command line

```r
outcome <- read.csv("Assigment3/outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
temp <- subset(outcome, State =="NY", select=c(Hospital.Name, Pneumonia)
```

it works and it creates the temp data frame with 2 columns the Hospital.Name and Pneumonia.

but when I create a function that contains the same instruction

state is a value inside the state column, and outcome1 is just the column name

```r
best <- function(state, outcome1) {
    outcome <- read.csv("Assigment3/outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")  
    temp <- subset(outcome, State ==state, select=c(Hospital.Name, outcome1))
}
```

and I call the function:

```
best("NY","Pneumonia")
```

I get the error:

> Error in [.data.frame`(x, r, vars, drop = drop) :
> undefined columns selected

I know the problem is with the `outcome1` variable, since when if I hardcode `outcome1` in the above function, instead of passing it in as an argument, the function works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `get` around your `outcome1` in your function definition, as you are passing a string rather than an object as your argument. With this example data:

```
outcome <- data.frame(Pneumonia = sample(0:1, size = 5, replace = TRUE),
                      State = c("NY", "NY", "NY", "CA", "CA"),
                      Hospital.Name = LETTERS[1:5]
                      )
```

And this modified function:

```
best <- function(df_, state_, var_) {
  subset(df_, State == state_, select = c(Hospital.Name, get(var_)))
}
```

Now you can call it more or less as before:

```
> best(df_ = outcome, state_ = "NY", var_ = "Pneumonia")
  Hospital.Name Pneumonia
1             A         0
2             B         1
3             C         0
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to show an example without the data but you can subset cols which may or may not be in your data.frame like this.  You could add a line in your function right after your subset command.  (and than don't drop cols in the subset line)

```
colnames( mtcars) 
# the cols you want to drop
drops <- c("mpg","colthatdoesntexisit","wt")
# drop those cols if they exisit in df
mtcars <- mtcars[ , !( names( mtcars) %in% drops ) ]
colnames( mtcars)
```

Answer (score 0):

As this post comes up as the top hit when searching for `"r undefined columns selected"`, here are some examples that can cause the error:

There is no column x

```
mtcars[, "x" ]
# Error in `[.data.frame`(mtcars, , "x") : undefined columns selected
```

Misspelled an existing column name - typo

```
colnames(mtcars)
#[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
mtcars[, "Mpg" ]
#Error in `[.data.frame`(mtcars, , "Mpg") : undefined columns selected
```

Subset by column index, which doesn't exist

```
ncol(mtcars)
#[1] 11
mtcars[, 12 ]
#Error in `[.data.frame`(mtcars, , 12) : undefined columns selected
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
temp <- subset(outcome, State =="NY", select=c(State, Hospital.Name, Pneumonia)
```

I am assuming you wish to keep the `State` field in your data frame.

Comment: this is the same as the first option I am trying without using the function "best", the problem I am getting is when I use it inside a function and state becomes a variable and the column name is the other variable

Comment: This doesn't attempt to answer the question. The question is specifically about passing in the value of `outcome` as an argument to the function.

Comment: @divibisan - there is not enough information in the question to indicate that is the problem?